# Junit . How to test a method that return a class object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

The Myclass has a method getdata(String name). which return the Student class object after calling the setter method So how to write the test for this the code is here....

```
class Myclass { 
    Student st = new Student();
    public Student getdata(String name){
        st.setName(name);
        return st;
    }
}
```

I want to test weather the st is null or not

Comment: Same question as before: what specifically are you trying to test? That the student's name is being set? Are you testing your `getdata` logic, or that Java setters work?

Answer (score 2):

If the `Student` class has a `getName` method then you could just test that:

```
Myclass obj = new Myclass();
final String NAME = "bob";
Student student = obj.getdata(NAME);
assertThat(student.getName(), is(NAME));
```

However, the code you have posted looks a bit suspicious to me - if you call `getdata` twice with different names you are updating the same `Student` object twice, is that really what you want to happen?

```
Student student1 = obj.getdata("mitchell");
Student student2 = obj.getdata("webb");
// student1 and student2 are the same object, with the name 'webb'
```